# How to get the data of the most recent completed form from "sheet 1" per client number in "sheet number 2"

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have two sheets:

Sheet 1: A sheet with subscribers linked to a Google Form which contains the following columns:

- Client number
- Subscribe date and time
- Answer 1
- Answer 2

These four columns contain the data a participant fills in via the Google Form. Every time a participant (client) fills in the form, a new row automatically will be created in this sheet. A participant can subscribe to the form more than once.

Sheet 2: A list with the same columns (not linked to a Google Form).

My goal is to get the data of the most recent completed form from "sheet 1" per client number in "sheet number 2".

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: This could be easily achieved using VBA, is this an option?

Comment: If sorting the second sheet is possible each time that is requested, then you can simply use ```VLOOKUP``` when the sheet2 is sorted by the date from top to bottom.
As Xabier mentioned though, VBA could be a very easy solution for the problem

Comment: You keep saying Google Form, is this Excel or Google Sheets?

Comment: Google form is a program of google which produces surveys etc.
Google Spreadsheet is excel online at google

Comment: I understand, I just wanted to ensure that you were not using google sheets with this as it would change a lot.  Many people think that Google sheets and Excel are interchangeable.  vba would be the best method.

Comment: Thankyou for your reactions. Is this also possible when you want to search from data out of multiple sheets in one excel file? And how can i do that?

Comment: Since the question mentions that the Google Form creates automatically a new row in the sheet, the spreadsheet applications is Google Sheets, not Excel and in such case [tag:google-spreadsheet] should be used instead of [tag:excel]